# как прописывать путь к изображениям в объект с данными

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, view

как прописывать путь к изображениям в объект с данными, думаю мой способ не самый лучший

```js
import React from 'react';
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';
import adamex from '@assets/sliderMain/Adamex.jpg';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const swiperParams = {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
  }
};


const slideData = [
  {
    title: 'Adamex',
    url: adamex
  },
  {},
  {}
];

const Slide = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 70rem;
  background-image: url(${adamex});
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;

const SliderMain = () => {

  return(
    <Swiper {...swiperParams}>
      <Slide>
        <h1>1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab amet animi
          architecto asperiores consectetur consequatur cum, doloribus dolorum eligendi fuga
          fugiat incidunt iure, iusto minima necessitatibus praesentium, quasi repellendus suscipit.</p>
      </Slide>
      <Slide>
        <h1>2</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab amet animi
            architecto asperiores consectetur consequatur cum, doloribus dolorum eligendi fuga
            fugiat incidunt iure, iusto minima necessitatibus praesentium, quasi repellendus suscipit.</p>
      </Slide>
    </Swiper>
  );
};

export default SliderMain;
```

Answer (score 0):

можно так:

```
import image1 from "./img/1.png";
import image2 from "./img/2.png";
import image3 from "./img/3.png";

const arr = [
  { id: 1, title: "1", img: image1 },
  { id: 2, title: "2", img: image2 },
  { id: 3, title: "3", img: image3 }
];
```